# Why should I Formalise the Daneland?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I'm an Emperor and I've conquered many lands.

I've found out I'll soon be able to "Formalise the Daneland", and reading the description this would basically destroy both England (a vassal of mine) and Danelaw (mine) to form a new Daneland (still mine).

So… what's in it for me? Why should the new one be better than the old one? Two Kingdoms look better than one… is there some hidden pro I'm missing?

Don't really care about de-jure claims, if that's it: I can conquer all I like anyway with Conquest casus belli…

PS: plus, it's not clear which will be the default succession of the new Kingdom. If it's not Feudal Elective as my current one, this will basically be a net loss of 1500 Prestige in order to turn it elective again…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will cut out the king of England, which means one less powerful vassal to worry about.

That's as if you were holding both England and Danelaw, and you get the taxes and troops from all the vassals in them without the "not my de jure liege" penalty. Further, those two kingdoms won't get separated due to inheritance shenanigans.

Answer (score 3):

Daneland has Scandinavian culture and Scandinavian elective inheritance. Formalising the Danelaw is the cheapest way to get them if you didn't have them already.

If you didn't already own England, then you'd get de jure ownership of it. If you want the King of England to hate you for some reason, that also happens.

If you already have all of that, then all you get is some alt-historical flavour.